# memcpy implementation in linux kernel

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, memcpy

I see `memcpy` implementation in linux kernel in real mode:

```
GLOBAL(memcpy)
    pushw   %si
    pushw   %di
    movw    %ax, %di
    movw    %dx, %si
    pushw   %cx
    shrw    $2, %cx
    rep; movsl
    popw    %cx
    andw    $3, %cx
    rep; movsb
    popw    %di
    popw    %si
    retl
ENDPROC(memcpy)
```

I understand first part before `rep; movsl`, but why is the second part after `rep; movsl`, it already copied from `si` -> `di` by 32 bytes. Why is the second part, i see only one reason to make coping again that structure which address is in `si` not aligned by 4 bytes.

Thank you.

Comment: Might be faster. And don't bother about real-mode code in the kernel. It runs only once at boot time.

Comment: Yes i know that it runs only in boot time, just interesting implementation of this

Comment: First `length / 4` doublewords are copied, then the remaining bytes (`length & 3`) - if any - are copied.

Comment: ah, yes, missed `andw`, assembly is not the best readable language. @Michael thank you. Can you post answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the relevant lines of code with comments to explain what they do:

```
shrw    $2, %cx   ; length /= sizeof(DWORD)
rep; movsl        ; Copy the first length/sizeof(DWORD) DWORDs
popw    %cx       ; Restore the original length
andw    $3, %cx   ; length &= 3, i.e. length %= sizeof(DWORD)
rep; movsb        ; Copy the remaining length % sizeof(DWORD) bytes (if any)
```